# Error in ncol(xj) : object 'xj' not found when using R matplot()

Tags: r

Using `matplot`, I'm trying to plot the 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns of `airquality` data.frame after dividing these 3 columns by the first column of `airquality`.

However I'm getting an error

```
Error in ncol(xj) : object 'xj' not found
```

Why are we getting this error? The code below will reproduce this problem.

```
attach(airquality)
airquality[2:4] <- apply(airquality[2:4], 2, function(x) x /airquality[1]) 
matplot(x= airquality[,1], y= as.matrix(airquality[-1]))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have managed to mangle your data in an interesting way.  Starting with `airquality` before you mess with it.  (And please don't `attach()` - it's unnecessary and sometimes dangerous/confusing.)

```
str(airquality)
'data.frame':   153 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Ozone  : int  41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
 $ Solar.R: int  190 118 149 313 NA NA 299 99 19 194 ...
 $ Wind   : num  7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
 $ Temp   : int  67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
 $ Month  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

After you do

```
airquality[2:4] <- apply(airquality[2:4], 2, 
                          function(x) x /airquality[1])
```

you get

```
'data.frame':   153 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Ozone  : int  41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
 $ Solar.R:'data.frame':    153 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Ozone: num  4.63 3.28 12.42 17.39 NA ...
 $ Wind   :'data.frame':    153 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Ozone: num  0.18 0.222 1.05 0.639 NA ...
 $ Temp   :'data.frame':    153 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Ozone: num  1.63 2 6.17 3.44 NA ...
 $ Month  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

or

```
sapply(airquality,class)
##        Ozone      Solar.R         Wind         Temp        Month          Day 
##     "integer" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame"    "integer"    "integer"
```

that is, [you have data frames embedded within your data frame!](https://imgflip.com/i/tff5g)

```
rm(airquality)  ## clean up
```

Now change *one character* and divide by the column `airquality[,1]` rather than `airquality[1]` (divide by a vector, not a list of length one ...)

```
airquality[,2:4] <- apply(airquality[,2:4], 2, 
                         function(x) x/airquality[,1])
matplot(x= airquality[,1], y= as.matrix(airquality[,-1]))
```

In general it's safer to use `[, ...]` indexing rather than `[]` indexing to refer to columns of a data frame unless you really know what you're doing ...

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe it should be stressed that `apply` is for `matrix` and `array` objects; here the right function to use is `lapply`, since `airquality` is a `data.frame` (and hence a `list`). Or one could coerce to `matrix` the object to start with (here it makes sense, since the goal is to call `matplot`).